# Can Windows be set up to automatically launch an application when an HID-compliant USB device is plugged in?

Tags: windows, usb, hid, autoplay

I have a custom HID-compliant USB device. I would like to set up Windows to launch an application when this device is plugged in. Is this possible through a configuration setting? Or do I need to write an application (for example, one that resides in the system tray on Windows startup) that detects when the device is inserted?

I know that my Canon camera and my Nokia phone can start applications or AutoPlay when they are plugged in, but they are not HID devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by monitoring for a WMI Win32_DeviceChangeEvent, or RegisterDeviceNotification.

- Win32_DeviceChangeEvent: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394124(VS.85).aspx
- RegisterDeviceNotification: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363431(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Which means option (b) write an application that's always running and detects the insertion.

Comment: Thanks very much for the info. I certainly have no problem with this approach. But what is different about the Canon Camera device that allows its events to be recognized by Windows?

Comment: Windows itself runs such an application monitoring device changes. When the device is recognised as an imaging device it leaps into action.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but what does Canon do so that Windows shows the device in the AutoPlay Control Panel? I'd like to do the same with my device.

Comment: Good question - not the same question though!